# Достать детей из Canvas в ItemControl

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Как мне получить в классе всех детей от канвас?

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="Control">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Name="RootPanel">
            <controls:MyCanvas x:Name="CanvasRoot"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Collage">
            <Grid/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Получить их нужно в моем классе:

```
public class MyCanvas : Canvas{}
```

Comment: `this.Children`?

Comment: Уже разобрался, нужно было сначала получить сам канвас, а потом его родителя 'ItemsControl' и тогда уже детей

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ очень простой. Сначала получил свой 'Canvas' как UI элемент и получить его родителя

```
 var canvas = this;
 var parent= (UIElement) VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(canvas);
```